# Mysql query based on group by return only one row

Tags: mysql, sql

There are two tables. First table received with group by. Second received with out group by.
[image]

When I use group by I get only first same row. Maybe exist some way how I can get all rows group by field sector_name:

```
select engine4_image_uploads.sector_id, engine4_image_gyms.gym, engine4_storage_sectors.sector_name, engine4_image_uploads.route_author, engine4_image_uploads.route_name, engine4_image_uploads.difficulty_grade 
from engine4_storage_sectors 
inner join engine4_image_gyms on engine4_storage_sectors.gym_name = engine4_image_gyms.gym inner 
join engine4_image_uploads on engine4_image_uploads.sector_id = engine4_storage_sectors.sector_id 
where engine4_image_gyms.gym = 'test4' 
group by sector_name
```

Comment: good practice to use all select fields in group by condition.

Comment: @first https://www.psce.com/blog/2012/05/15/mysql-mistakes-do-you-use-group-by-correctly/

Comment: What exactly should your output look like? If you use `group by`, you get one row per group. That is what `group by` does. If you don't want that, don't use `group by` (or use it differently, e.g. in a subquery). Are you maybe looking for `order by`, which might be something someone (not familiar with databases) might describe as "group together all rows with the same sectorname"?

Comment: The first thing you should say is what you wanted in the result.  Then you specify your problem and your query.  We can't help since we don't know what you want.